# Removed and Reinstalled Wordpress, Redirect Broken now

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, permissions

I just removed and reinstalled wordpress, I think something messed up..

Now when I enter URL, such as "test123.com", nothing load..

The ".htaccess" file on root folder is empty.

and content of "index.php" here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Now wordpress is installed on "/wdps" folder.

Also, here are their permission setting, is there something wrong??

/.htaccess:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s74/sh/9d3b8f33-b26d-4f19-b35c-958b1e9600ff/41b1d7015fee992c36b1cb66651e40f5

/index.php: 
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s74/sh/11010e56-f29c-4507-b131-ae06cf22e0bf/e859f5ad1f42919ddde25e5c27812ed5

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: Debugging information?? What you mean?

Answer (score 0):

change this line in your `index.php` on root from

```
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

to

```
require('./wdps/wp-blog-header.php');
```

then make an `.htaccess` file on root like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wdps/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wdps/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```